# VBA How to copy data from a sheet and paste to a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am coming across two errors with my below code. First one is i cant get it to accept my custom naming convention for the file. This is needed as multiple files will be added daily and a copy of each is needed.

The Second and more pressing is that it is able to open up a new workbook but fails to copy any of the data across.

I have looked at other versions of copy and paste data to a new sheet but still came across the same problems.

```
Sub CompleteAndAddToUploadFile_Click()
Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Frank Import Full List")
    Set wbO = Workbooks.Add

    With wbO
        Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\first.last\Documents\testing\" & "-" & wbI.Worksheets("Ssafa Email Dump").Range("D17") & "-" & Format(Now, "DDMMYY") & ".csv", FileFormat:=56
        wsI.Range("A1:f60").Copy
        wsO.Range("A1:f60").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

What i require in the end is for the data to be copied from the active workbook from the sheet Frank Import Full List and pasted into a new document with the name of Worksheets("Ssafa Email Dump").Range("D17") todays date and then saved as a CSV

Edit: Issue one customer naming convention fixed

Comment: I'm guessing you need at least `wbI.Worksheets("Ssafa Email Dump").Range("D17")` as otherwise it's looking in the other workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Self Fixed.

Turned out the only error that was holding it back was user error :/.

Above code worked fine after fix from @SJR to include "wbI." in the line Worksheets ("Ssafa Email Dump") etc

Thank you all for you time and help